# Testing a Large Application with Multiple UI Maps

Tags: visual-studio-2012, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I have to implement multiple UIMap.cs in coded ui project. I have added multiple UIMap as given on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398056.aspx, however when I start recording system display message 'The Action was not recoded because access to application was denied' and does not generate any code for method.

Is there any thing I am missing other than setting given above given url.

Your input will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb large application should not be recorded but code should be hand written.

This will allow you to maintain your code better and for example build classes for modules of your app.